# How can i draw a line on the terrain when moving the mouse around?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DrawLinesWithMouse : MonoBehaviour
{
    private List<Vector3> pointsList;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        pointsList = new List<Vector3>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        RaycastHit hit;

        Ray ray = GetComponent<Camera>().ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 1000))
        {
            Vector3 hitpoint = hit.point;
            pointsList.Add(hitpoint);

            DrawLine(pointsList[0], pointsList[pointsList.Count -1], Color.red, 0.2f);
        }
    }

    void DrawLine(Vector3 start, Vector3 end, Color color, float duration = 0.2f)
    {
        GameObject myLine = new GameObject();
        myLine.transform.position = start;
        myLine.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
        LineRenderer lr = myLine.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        lr.material = new Material(Shader.Find("Particles/Alpha Blended Premultiply"));
        lr.startColor = color;
        lr.startWidth = 3f;
        lr.endWidth = 3f;
        lr.SetPosition(0, start);
        lr.SetPosition(1, end);
        //GameObject.Destroy(myLine, duration);
    }
}
```

The problem here is that it's drawing a line like handheld folding fan:

[image: handheld folding fan]

But i want it to draw a line just single line according to the mouse movement position including curves if for example i move the mouse in circles, not only straight lines.

Comment: I suggest, you should check [Trail Renderer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TrailRenderer.html) . You can add an empty gameObject to your mouse Position, which will have trailRenderer on it.

Comment: Instead of drawing from pt0 to current point, u may want to draw from currentPt -1 to currentPt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DrawLine(pointsList[0], pointsList[pointsList.Count -1], Color.red, 0.2f);
```

This part is drawing from the first point (poinstList[0]) to the last point (pointsList[pointsList.Count -1]).
It should instead draw from the second to last point to the last point.

```
DrawLine(pointsList[pointsList.Count -2], pointsList[pointsList.Count -1], Color.red, 0.2f);
```